# Subsetting an "xts" (matrix) where elements exceed a given threshold

Tags: r, matrix, xts, subset

Consider an xts matrix similar to:

```
> x=xts(matrix(1:12, ncol=3), Sys.Date()+1:4  )
> x[1,]=NA
> x
           [,1] [,2] [,3]
2014-01-15   NA   NA   NA
2014-01-16    2    6   10
2014-01-17    3    7   11
2014-01-18    4    8   12
```

To get elements exceeding, say, 4:

```
>   coredata(x)[x>4]
[1] NA NA  6  7  8 NA 10 11 12
```

and without NAs:

```
>    coredata(x)[!is.na(x) & x >4]
[1]  6  7  8 10 11 12
```

NAs don't select elements in `x` so the following works without nullify the first line too:

```
>   coredata(x)[x>4]=0
> x
           [,1] [,2] [,3]
2014-01-15   NA   NA   NA
2014-01-16    2    0    0
2014-01-17    3    0    0
2014-01-18    4    0    0
```

The question is: is this subsetting method  efficient when `x` is large or is there any more xts specific approach?

Comment: If you don't care about index of the xts object, this method should be efficient as you are directly dealing with matrix data.

Comment: @ChinmayPatil: Actually it would be nice to just do `x[x>4]`. Since xts class claims to be matrix like, I thought  there were a better alternative to converting/extracting the matrix via `coredata`.

Comment: You don't need `coredata` for that assignment.  You can just do `x[x>4] <- 0`

Answer (score 1):

You can try `which=TRUE` argument while subsetting

```
x = xts(matrix(1:12, ncol = 3), Sys.Date() + 1:4)
x[1, ] = NA
x[x > 4, which = T]
## [1]  6  7  8 10 11 12
```